# Problema de repetição de variável em PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um pequeno joguinho, onde simula RPG de turnos. eu criei duas variáveis para a vida do jogador e do inimigo, e então criei duas variáveis para as suas ações (se cair em um certo número, fará tal ação).

O problema é que eu quero por uma ação de defesa, que diminuiria o ataque recebido pela metade, mas não sei como colocar isso. Eu tentei colocar uma variável que mudaria em cada if diferente, mas isso faria com que o ataque de um deles não fosse atualizado, fazendo o personagem receber o último número que foi registrado na variável.

```
       $player =100;
        $enemy= 100;

        while ($enemy > 0)
        {
            $ataque = rand(1, 4)
        echo '
        1 - ataque<br>
        2- defesa <br>
        3- tomar poção<br>
        4- bola de fogo<br>
        <input type="text" name="action">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">"   ';
            if(isset($_GET["action"]))
            {
                    $action= $_GET["action"];
                    if($action== 1)
                    {
                        $player = $player - 15;
                        echo "<br>você deu um ataque no seu inimigo. causando 15 de dano";
                        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
                    }

                    if($action== 2)
                    {

                        $dano = $golpe/2;
                        $player = $player - $dano;
                        echo "<br>você se defendeu do ataque do inimigo, recebendo metade do dano";
                        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
                    }
                    if($ataque == 1)
                    {
                        $golpe = 15;
                        echo "<br>ele te deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano.";
                        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
                    }
                    if($ataque == 2)
                    {
                        $enemy = $enemy - 5;
                        echo "<br>Ele se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano";
                        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código tem alguns erros de lógica, e falta alguns ';' (não se só transcreveu para cá errado ou se está no código), e o 'while' no começo gera infinitos inputs, então reescrevi o código e está funcionando.

```html
<? 
if($_GET["player"] != null) { //verifica se já foi enviado a vida do player
    $player = $_GET['player']; 
} else {
    $player = 100; //valor inicial
}
if($_GET["enemy"] != null) { //verifica se já foi enviado a vida do player
    $enemy = $_GET['enemy'];
} else {
    $enemy = 100; //valor inicial
}

$dano = 15; //valor padrão do golpe
        
if(isset($_GET["action"])) {

    $ataque = rand(1, 2); 
    $action= $_GET["action"];
    
    if($action == 1 && $ataque == 1) { //Se ambos atacarem
        $enemy -= $dano;
        $player -= $dano;
        echo "<br>ele te deu um ataque, causando 15 de dano.";
        echo "<br>você deu um ataque no seu inimigo. causando 15 de dano";
        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
    } elseif($action == 1 && $ataque == 2) { //Se vc atacar e o inimigo defender
        $enemy -= $dano / 2;
        echo "<br>Ele se defendeu, recebendo só metade do dano";
        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
    } elseif($action == 2 && $ataque == 1) { //Se vc defender e o inimigo atacar
        $player -= $dano / 2;
        echo "<br>você se defendeu do ataque do inimigo, recebendo metade do dano";
        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
    } else { // se ambos se defenderem
        echo "<br>ambos se defenderam, ninguém leva dano";
        echo "<br>Você: ".$player."<br>Inimigo: ".$enemy;
    }
}

if($enemy <= 0) { //verifica se a vida do inimigo zerou
    echo '<br>você venceu o inimigo';
} elseif($player <= 0) { //verifica se sua vida zerou
    echo '<br>você perdeu para o inimigo';
} else {
    echo '
    <form action="?" method="get">
        <br>1- ataque<br>
        2- defesa <br>
        3- tomar poção<br>
        4- bola de fogo<br>
        <input type="hidden" name="player" value="'.$player.'"> // envia a sua vida para o próximo evento
        <input type="hidden" name="enemy" value="'.$enemy.'"> // envia a vida do seu inimigo para o próximo evento
        <input type="text" name="action">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>';
}
```

Comment: Eu estava ciente dos erros, isso porque eu estava adicionando mais coisas, como opção de cura e de um ataque mais forte, por isso deu conflito com a opção de bloquear. Mas o código que escreveu está excelente, obrigado pela ajuda.